# wrapping jquery ui autocomplete results in a href

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I use this function to wrap the results of the jquery ui autocomplete function in an hyperlink. It fails to do that. It just displays the label item. Any suggestion here?

```
[{"value":"morzine","label":"Morzine"},{"value":"grachen","label":"Grachen"},{"value":"fiesch","label":"Fiesch"},{"value":"zermatt","label":"Zermatt"},{"value":"saas-fee","label":"Saas Fee"},{"value":"bettmeralp","label":"Bettmeralp"},{"value":"riederalp","label":"Riederalp"},{"value":"jeizinen","label":"Jeizinen"},{"value":"crans-montana","label":"Crans Montana"},{"value":"simplon-dorf","label":"Simplon Dorf"}]

$("#srch").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function (a, b) {
        $.getJSON("http://skiweather.eu/v3/ajax/search.php?q=" + a.term + "&format=json", function (a) {
            b(a)
        })
    },
    select: function (a, b) {
        $("#srch").val(b.item.label);
        return false
    },
    focus: function (a, b) {
        $("#srch").val(b.item.label);
        return false
    }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (a, b) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", b)
        .append('<a href="/webcams/' + b.value + '"> ' + b.label + '</a>  ')
        .appendTo(a)
}
```

Comment: What exactly is failing to happen? I bet the `<a>` tag is there--is the problem that it's not navigating to the location when you click it?

Comment: yes, that is what is going wrong, but the append section is also wrong.

Comment: how does your json from http://skiweather.eu/v3/ajax/search.php?q=" + a.term + "&format=json" look like? i am sure that is not the one you have pasted in the first line as it doesnot haveresort_name and resort_us properties.

Comment: Yes, it is like the json I pasted. Made some changes to the js-code to match the jason file (value, label). Not returning hyperlinks (not clickable)

Comment: If you like to test: http://skiweather.eu/webcams/wallis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.data('ui-autocomplete')` if you're using jQueryUI >= 1.10. If you look at the console for your website, you'll see the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined

```
$("#srch").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: /* ... */,
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (a, b) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", b)
        .append('<a href="/webcams/' + b.value + '"> ' + b.label + '</a>  ')
        .appendTo(a);
};
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Aa5nK/51/

Also, unrelated, but I would recommend using more understandable variable names (something more descriptive than `a` and `b`).